# Convergence-test using density exists?

Tags: number-theory, convergence-divergence, density-function

Let $0<a_n$. I want to declare that $\sum 1/a_n$ is convergent (or divergent) based on the behaviour of the density $S_n/n$, as $n\to\infty$, where $S_n$ is the number of elements of $a_n$ falling into $(0,n)$. For example, if $a_n$ is the n-th prime, then $S_n/n$ is about $1/\ln n$, and we know that the sum is divergent. Is the opposite true? I.e., from $S_n/n$ is about $1/\ln n$ does it follow that $\sum 1/a_n$  is convergent? Yes or no?

Comment: Are the $a_n$ integers, or arbitrary positive real numbers?

Comment: @DanielFischer Is that really important?

Comment: @Dave A sequence of positive terms is convergent _iff_ it is absolutely convergent, in which case you may reorder the terms any way you like. It seems natural to order them by decreasing.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Only for convenience. If we look at a set of positive integers, Abel's sum formula gives a pretty convenient answer at least in the cases where $S_n/n$ is well-behaved. In the general case, it's going to be more work.

Comment: Does this Abel's sum method works for at least the prime numbers? Then we don't talk about nothing, good job, in that case.